# SWI-Prolog split the list into ordered decreased lists

Tags: prolog

I would really appreciate it if someone has a solution that splits the list into ordered decreased lists. The order of elements must be the same as the input list.
I have made some tasks in Prolog, but that was much easier, now I don't even know where to start .
For example 
[5,4,2,8,3,1,6,9,5] -> [5,4,2],[8,3,1],[6],[9,5].

Comment: Please define 'ordered decreased list'; are duplicates allowed in there? E.g. `[9,5,5,1] --> [9,5],[5,1]` or `[9,5,5,1] --> [9,5,5,1]`?

Comment: I'm sorry for giving you not full question . [9,5,5,1] --> [9,5,5,1], duplicates allowed

Comment: What you have isn't a question, but a request for someone to write your code for you, which isn't what this site is about. Please show what you've tried and ask a specific question regarding where you are stuck. If you don't know where to start, then I'd recommend a Prolog tutorial, and perhaps have a look through [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/), focusing on list processing.

Comment: "now I don't even know where to start" start at the beginning: write the algorithm down, in words or in pseudocode. Take in consideration what data structures you are using (a list in Prolog is a "stack", not a contiguous  array). Once you have the data structures and the algorithm in place, attempt to write it down in Prolog. If you run into trouble, come back to Stackoverflow and _ask a real question_.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [CapelliC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303247/8015575) here you should be able to use nearly the same pattern matching for a descending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
'ascending([A], [[A]]).
ascending([A,B|T], R) :-
    ( A < B -> R = [[A],P|Q] ; P = [M|N], R = [[A,M|N]|Q] ),
    ascending([B|T], [P|Q]).'
```